# BS3 just only the one tab working, why?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I developed message system with bootstrap 3 tabs (*bs3 tab info: http://getbootstrap....nents/#nav-tabs*)
Of course I am using its vertical to style. So there is following;

[image: my message system]

I am just sending to **Mustafa** member', I can't send to **Alican** member'.
This page's design before left side (so tab-title) get php listing to messages titles (with MySQL DISTINCT). Then so the same code getting messages.

*All this page's code I linked paste.bin: http://pastebin.com/ekqf7dL9*

The Yellow button, (so it is "submit button") jquery posting with ajax my request to php file. There is its code;

```
<button m_isim="<?php echo $_SESSION['uyeIsim'];?>" m_atan="<?php echo $_SESSION['uyeId'];?>" m_alan="<?php echo $msjGelenUye['mesaj_alan_id'];?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Gönder</button>
```

Information about the variable

```
$_SESSION['uyeIsim'] -> user name
$msjGelenUye['mesaj_alan_id'] -> user reciever
m_atan -> transmitter
```

jQuery post code following;

```
$("#btn-chat").click(function(event){
    var msjGonderenData = {
        "mesaj_atan_id" : $(this).attr('m_atan'), //user transmitter
        "mesaj_alan_id" : $(this).attr('m_alan'), //user receiver
        "mesaj"         : $("#btn-chat-input").val() //message content
    };

    var msjAtanIsim = $(this).attr('m_isim'); //transmitter name

    //alert(msjGonderenData['mesaj']);  //just control, This is "Mustafa" working but "Alican" doesn't work

    $.ajax({
        type        :"POST",
        url         :"inc/request/msjGonder.post.php",
        data        :msjGonderenData,
        success     :function(cvp){
            if(cvp != "1"){
                $(".postCevap").html(cvp);
            }else{
                //add current message list sent message
                $("ul#"+msjGonderenData['mesaj_alan_id']+".chat").append("<li class=\"right clearfix\"><span class=\"chat-img pull-right\"><img src=\"http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text="+msjAtanIsim+"\" alt=\"\" /></span><div class=\"chat-body clearfix\"><div class=\"header\"><small class=\"text-muted\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-time\"></span>&nbsp;Şimdi</small><strong class=\"pull-right primary-font\">"+msjAtanIsim+"</strong></div><p>"+msjGonderenData['mesaj']+"</p></div></li>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

*msjGonder.post.php* following code;

```
<?php

include '../db.connect.php';
//bootstrapAlertBox
$msj_atan =  $_POST['mesaj_atan_id']; //transmitter
$msj_alan =  $_POST['mesaj_alan_id']; //reciever
$msj =  $_POST['mesaj'];

if(!isset($msj)){
    echo bootstrapAlertBox("info","<b>Boş</b> mesaj gönderemezsiniz !");
}else{
    try{
        $mdb->insert("mesaj",array(
            'mesaj_atan_id' => $msj_atan,
            'mesaj_alan_id' => $msj_alan,
            'mesaj' => $msj,
            'tarih' => getDateTime(),
            'ip' => getIP()
        ));
        echo "1";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo bootstrapAlertBox("danger","<b>Bilinmedik Hata: <u>".$e->getMessage()."</u> Lütfen tekrar deneyin.</b>");
    }
}
?>
```

How do solve this ?
Thank you for interest.

Best regards..

**Added** for (@Franky)

Hmm, I guess understood. Firstly my code translate to html standart (so I added attributes before **data-**)
For instance, `m_isim -> data-m-isim`

Secondly, I deleted repeat every `ID` attributes. After these operations first and second tabs can be request the POST.

I think there is some my did mistakes. I don't know them. Because I don't found :/ (What interesting code I write?)
Second tab posting but data added first tab inside (both empty and added added db by first tab id). Chat list tag is `ul` I transform it to this;

`<ul class="chat">` -> `<ul class="chat" data-code="r21>">`, *r21*; r is constant and 21 number is user receiver id (from db)

I couldn't this problem solved.
jQuery last codes following;

```
var mesajAlanId = $("span.input-group-btn button").data('m-alan');

$("span.input-group-btn").click(function(event){
    var msjGonderenData = {
        "mesaj_atan_id" : $(".receiver-"+mesajAlanId).data('m-atan'), //user transmitter
        "mesaj_alan_id" : $(".receiver-"+mesajAlanId).data('m-alan'), //user receiver
        "mesaj"         : $("input[data-receiver-text=\""+mesajAlanId+"\"]").val() //message content alan_id
    };

    var msjAtanIsim = $(".receiver-"+mesajAlanId).data('m-isim'); //transmitter name

    alert(msjGonderenData.mesaj);

    $.ajax({
        type        :"POST",
        url         :"inc/request/msjGonder.post.php",
        data        :msjGonderenData,
        success     :function(cvp){
            $(':input','.input-group').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
            if(cvp != "1"){
                $(".postCevap-"+mesajAlanId).html(cvp);
            }else{
                //add current message list sent message
                //msjGonderenData.mesaj_alan_id
                $("ul.chat[data-code='r"+msjGonderenData.mesaj_alan_id+"']").append("<li class=\"right clearfix\"><span class=\"chat-img pull-right\"><img src=\"http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text="+msjAtanIsim+"\" alt=\"\" /></span><div class=\"chat-body clearfix\"><div class=\"header\"><small class=\"text-muted\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-time\"></span>&nbsp;Şimdi</small><strong class=\"pull-right primary-font\">"+msjAtanIsim+"</strong></div><p>"+msjGonderenData.mesaj+"</p></div></li>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Live codes updated;
http://famousbook.org/beta-test123321

user-name: **fatihmert**

password: **sanane123** and, Refresh page when you did login. Right top corner, inbox > see all.

Comment: what part is not working..? where specifically are you facing the problem.

Comment: @Franky , Actually my code hasn't got a issue. But just working submit button (so yellow button) under the **Mustafa** tab-title. (I'm talking about the jquery). **Mustafa** tab-title doesn't work outside. (so just first tab working. 2nd, 3rd , .. , Nrd tabs doesn't work)

Comment: I caught video upload to youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx3EYPpWtho

Comment: can you provide a live url i will check for html and jquery code at my end

Comment: @Franky thank you for interest.
http://famousbook.org/beta-test123321/
user-name: **fatihmert**
password: **sanane123** and, Refresh page when you did login. Right top corner, inbox > see all.

Comment: I have identified the problem and posted a solution please let me know if it works for you, Change your password and delete your previous comment as it contains useful credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `HTML` code

Below is the html for `Mustafa`.

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Yasla gitsin..." class="form-control input-sm" id="btn-chat-input">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="btn-chat" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" m_alan="31" m_atan="18" m_isim="fatihmert">Gönder</button>
      </span>
    </div>
   <div class="postCevap"></div> 
</div>
```

Html For `Alican`.

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Yasla gitsin..." class="form-control input-sm" id="btn-chat-input">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="btn-chat" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" m_alan="21" m_atan="18" m_isim="fatihmert">Gönder</button>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="postCevap"></div>
</div>
```

The Button and the input field has same `id` which is not correct. That is why your code isn't working. Please use class for better compatibility of code.

Note: Avoid using `m_alan`, `m_atan`, `m_isim` for storing data in `Html` tags use the standard `data-m-alan`, `data-m-isim` && `data-m-atan` Instead.

Comment: I don't know these. Thank you @Frankly, Now It can do POST. But There's a mistake. My question's and live code updated. Lastly Can you see it?

Comment: Faith please delete the edit you have done and ask a new question for it. Its like a mess with previous question. And accept the answer so others like you can be helped. I will check your aplication.